# How can I search within specific values of apex data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am playing around with lwc and trying to build a simple search filter but I am trying to filter the search based on the billing city, country or state. At the moment, the search just goes over all the returned values but I dont want it to search for the names. I tried iterating the returned data like an object and excluded the name key and put the other values into an array but that does not work.

How can I do this correctly

```
Apex

public with sharing class filterClasses {
    public filterClasses() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled( cacheable = true )
    public static List<Account> fetchAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingCountry FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    
         
    }

   
}
```

```
LWC

<template>      
    <lightning-card title="Accounts filter">  
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">  
            <p>Filter Accounts</p>
            <lightning-input type="search" label="Search Account" onchange={handleSearch}></lightning-input><br/><br/>
            <template if:true={availableAccounts}>      
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={availableAccounts}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                    show-row-number-column="true"
                    >
                </lightning-datatable>  
            </template>      
            <template if:true={error}>  
                {error}>                  
            </template>  
        </div>  
    </lightning-card>
</template>


const columns = [   
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'BillingStreet', fieldName: 'BillingStreet' },
    { label: 'BillingCity', fieldName: 'BillingCity' },
    { label: 'BillingCountry', fieldName: 'BillingCountry' },

];

export default class Accountsfilter extends LightningElement {

    availableAccounts;
    error;
    columns = columns;
    searchString;
    initialRecords;


    @wire( fetchAccounts )  
    wiredAccount( { error, data } ) {

        if ( data ) {

            this.availableAccounts = data;
            this.initialRecords = data;
            this.error = undefined;

        } else if ( error ) {

            this.error = error;
            this.availableAccounts = undefined;

        }

    }

   

   

    handleSearch( event ) {

        const searchKey = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
       

        if ( searchKey ) {

       

           this.availableAccounts = this.initialRecords;
           
            
            if ( this.availableAccounts ) {

              

                let recs = [] 

                

                
                
                for ( let rec of this.availableAccounts ) {

                    
                   
                    
                    
                    let valuesArray = Object.values( rec );
                    
                    console.log(valuesArray)
 
                    for ( let val of valuesArray ) {

                     

                       
                        let strVal = String( val );

                        
                        if ( strVal ) {

                            if ( strVal.toLowerCase().includes( searchKey ) ) {

                                recs.push( rec );
                                break;
                        
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    
                }

                
                this.availableAccounts = recs;

             }
 
        }  else {

            this.availableAccounts = this.initialRecords;

        }        

    }

}
```

I am looking to search just billing state, country and city instead of all the values.

Comment: It is really unclear what your architecture is. Do you need to load all data to the FE and search locally? Can you delegate it to the backend?

Comment: @zaitsman I wanna search locally within the frontend. I have tried using filter and just trying to match the string with the keys if billing city, street and country but that doesn't work. I was only able to get it to work using the method above but that searches the name fields too. I only wanna filter using the billing fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what problem you are exactly facing here and if I have understood your requirement here correctly then the below sample should work:

.html:

```
<template>

    <lightning-card>

<lightning-input type="text"
                    placeholder="Filter Account"
                    value={searchValue}
                    onchange={searchKeyword}>
</lightning-input>
                
<lightning-datatable
            key-field="Id"
            data={output}
            columns={c}
</lightning-datatable>

   </lightning-card> 
    
</template>
```

.js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/filterClasses.fetchAccounts';

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'BillingStreet',
        fieldName: 'BillingStreet'
    }, {
        label: 'BillingCity',
        fieldName: 'BillingCity',
    }, {
        label: 'BillingCountry',
        fieldName: 'BillingCountry',
    }, 
];

export default class DynamicSearchInLWC extends LightningElement {
        
@track output;
searchValue = '';
c=columns       
        
        searchKeyword(event) {
   this.searchValue = event.target.value;  
      if (this.searchValue !== '') {

        fetchAccounts({
        searchKey: this.searchValue                   
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.output = result;
            
            })
                
    } 
}
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class filterClasses {
    

    @AuraEnabled( cacheable = true )
    public static List<Account> fetchAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingCountry FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    
         
    }

   
}
```

Please change the property names as per your need.

Comment: In the component when you are creating the input feild, you need to put "value={searchValue}" so that it can hold and pass on the data that is given as input in that field. In your case it was missing. I also did not do the error handling part, you may incorporate it as per your wish.

Comment: I need all the columns cause I wanna do some computerization on the name fields. I only wanna filter with the values in the billing fields. It's using all the values now to do the filtering.

Comment: In that case declare all those columns you want in the datatable in that part of .js where the columns are declared. And for filtering you said you want that on BillingCity so modify the SOQL query accordingly.

Comment: I did that but I get an error when I try to type. I can only search via the name fields or all the fields together.

Comment: Please put the error you are getting so that it is easier to solve.